# How to replace bullet points using macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and stuck in one problem, I want to replace Bullet points in excel with the comma, and copy that cell to another workbook Excel.

I have tried `CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(E5,"•",""))` and `(Replace(str40, "•", ","))` but both are not working.

Comment: The first formula works flawlessly for me - `=CLEAR(SUBSTITUTE(E5;"•";"~"))` Are you sure you are referencing correctly?

Comment: Both approaches also work fine on my end, perhaps it is a character/encoding issue?

Comment: Looking at the original and the answers, is the OP meant to be using commas as separators or semi-colons ? This will depend on his system settings...

Comment: @SolarMike : Thanks for your response could you please let me know where in the system setting ?

Comment: system preferences : language and region : advanced : number separators at least that is where they are on a mac...